# DNS resolving error

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I am using a linode running nginx. I wanted to have mail sending capabilities on my VPS, so I change the hostnames and reverse DNS but now I have messed up my DNS somehow and the site doesn't even resolve.

Here is what my DNS manager for the domain looks like
[image]

Here is what my Reverse DNS setting looks like (I changed it to `mail.bankpo.in`)
[image]

Content of `/etc/hostname` is `mail.bankpo.in`

Content of `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
178.79.162.174 mail.bankpo.in

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Command `hostname -f` gives `hostname: Name or service not known`

I have also rebooted it, but it seems like I have done something wrong. Any advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @rvs answer is more applicable in general case, linode users have to enter a blank hostname to fix the problem I was having of a missing A record-type. If you are not on linode, I would suggest rvs's answer will be more appropriate for you, so I am marking my answer as accepted and upvoting his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The site does not resolve because you've deleted @ entry (@ means no subdomain). According to your screenshot www.youdomain.com should resolve normally to 178.79.162.174, but yourdomain.com (without www) would not resolve.

Add A-type entry like @ IN 178.79.162.174 to fix this issue.

Your reverse dns entry looks fine. Please note, that your mail server should identify himself as mail.yourdomain.com, not yourdomain.com.

Also, you migth want to add spf TXT record to help spam filters (and avoid your mails being marked as spam). See here: http://old.openspf.org/dns.html

Comment: Consider me a noob please. while adding A-type record, what should be my hostname? http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/lh24t8hh/Selection_037.png

Comment: Also the question does have a screenshot for adding the reverse DNS entry. I can just enter the hostname and it will set that as a reverse dns entry.

Comment: Access denied for this image. Hostname should be '@' or 'bankpo.in.' (with '.' at the and - this is important).

Comment: May be your firewall or something, I can see that fine. I have added 'bankpo.in.' as the hostname and now I believe DNS will take full day to propagate, right? This alone should fix my problem, right? Once the site is up, I can get onto other things you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, this should fix it.